# How to call a function from main component in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Now I have a render function. I want too use it in my Main Component. How to use it?

This is my function  (function because i need to know how to use hooks)

```
//Left_Side
const Get_Data = () => {
    const id = useId();
    const [state, setState] = useState({sampleState: 'hola'})
   return (
   <div class="nav_container">
    <div class="nav_block">
        <a href='/about'>About</a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav_block">
        <a href='/Suma'>Sum</a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav_block">
        <a href='/Menos'>Menos</a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav_block">
        <a href='/data'>{this.state.name}</a>
    </div>
    <label htmlFor={id}> Please specify: </label>
    <input type="text" id={id} onInput={setState(e.target.value)}>
    </input>
    <button>
        {state}
    </button>
</div>)
   
}
```

This is My main-app component

```
const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOMClient.createRoot(container);

root.render(
  <div className='container'>
    <Left_Side {Get_Data}/>
</div>
)
```

This is not working. What am I doing wrong to call?

Comment: Where is `Left_Side` defined?

Comment: In another file from main. All code without imports are here